# scikit-learn, linearsvc - how to get support vectors from the trained SVM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using LinearSVC from scikit-learn library and I wonder if it is possible to somehow pull out the vectors which my model uses after training to make predictions. Tried to google it for some time but without any luck. Anyone knows?

Comment: I you mean support vectors, `LinearSVC` doesn't actually use those at all.

Comment: `LinearSVC` dosen't use support vector, but the concept still exists, and might be still useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately there seems to be no way to do that. LinearSVC calls liblinear ([see relevant code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/891839cd8d8d58a39f5ab0673abcb1c3fa377e17/sklearn/svm/classes.py#L182)) but doesn't retrieve the vectors, only the coefficients and the intercept.

One alternative would be to use SVC with the 'linear' kernel (libsvm instead of liblinear based), but also `poly`, `dbf` and `sigmoid` kernel support this option:

```
from sklearn import svm

X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
y = [0, 1]

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, y)
print clf.support_vectors_
```

**Output:**

```
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.]]
```

liblinear scales better to large number of samples, but otherwise the are mostly equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, Elyase. If I will use other types of SVC available in scikit-learn, will it be possible to return the vectors (or how to call them correctly if I use polynomal kernel) descriptions somehow?

Comment: When I try this I get clf.support_vectors_.shape as (4485, 2), presumably from all the different trial vectors as the algorithm attempts to optimise the fit. Is there a way to isolate the best performing support vector in this case (if I'm right in my interpretation)?

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if it helps, but I was searching for something similar and the conclusion was that when:

```
clf = svm.LinearSVC()
```

Then this:

```
clf.decision_function(x)
```

Is equal to this:

```
clf.coef_.dot(x) + clf.intercept_
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. In case of n classes, svm.SVC computes the decision function (one-vs-rest) from n*(n-1) classifiers and this is different from LinearSVC which just looks at the arg max from n classifiers.

Answer (score 3):

This could help you.

```
clf = svm.SVC( kernel='rbf',C=0.05)
clf.fit(traindata,y)
print clf.support_vectors_
```

This link can you more information if needed.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a way: I found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_linearsvc_support_vectors.html) how to obtain the support vectors from linearSVC - I'm reporting the relevant portion of code:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

clf = LinearSVC('''whatever fits your specs''')
clf.fit(X,y)
# get the support vectors through the decision function
decision_function = clf.decision_function(X)
# we can also calculate the decision function manually as previously noted
# decision_function = np.dot(X, clf.coef_[0]) + clf.intercept_[0]
# The support vectors are the samples that lie within the margin
# boundaries, whose size is conventionally constrained to 1
support_vector_indices = np.where(np.abs(decision_function) <= 1 + 1e-15)[0]
support_vectors = X[support_vector_indices]
```